# PHP File upload and tmp files

Tags: php

So I am making a class which handles my file uploading from a form. The problem I am having is during renaming the file from the temporary one, to the new one. My class gives the user the ability to manually specify the filename, or use the same name it was uploaded as. Now, If I manually set the name, I need to be able to know the extension to add to the file. Since the temp folder does not include extensions, and **I would prefer not to explode it at the period** from `$file['uploadedfile']['name']`, what would one suggest I do?

**I guess my initial question would be:** Is there any way to configure the server/php so it does not rename the file when it is placed in the temp folder, so I can use `pathinfo()` for the extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to configure the server/php so it does not rename the file when it is placed in the temp folder

No.

> what would one suggest I do?

Use the original extension, either the typed one or the one in `$_FILES[x]['name']`. What's wrong with that?

Comment: Will it handle files with 2 extensions?

Comment: @Headspin: If you're talking about pathinfo, no it will only take the last extension. But if you want to be able to do anything useful with an uploaded file you already need to understand its type anyway, which means you'll know what extension it ought to have. You can't *completely reliably* determine what is an extension and what is part of the name from mere string parsing.

Answer (score 0):

You can't control the temporary name, but you can use $_FILES['file']['name'] to get the original extension as this contains the name of the file from the user's computer.  You can pass that file name to pathinfo().  Of course just because the extension is one thing, doesn't mean the file is of that type.

```
var_dump(pathinfo('testfile.png'));

array(4) {
  ["dirname"]=>
  string(1) "."
  ["basename"]=>
  string(12) "testfile.png"
  ["extension"]=>
  string(3) "png"
  ["filename"]=>
  string(8) "testfile"
}
```

Comment: `pathinfo()` requires a path to a file as its argument. `$_FILES['file']['name']` is just the name.

Comment: Will this take into account if the file has 2 extensions?

Comment: Technically a file can only have one extension.  It would only return the string after the last period.  something.tar.gz is a gz file, pathinfo would have no way of knowing the difference between myfile.2011-01-01.13:23:00.txt, view.script.php or x.tar.gz